# Use R data.frame object in d3.js using r2d3

Tags: r, d3.js, r2d3

I'm trying to understand how an R data frame is passed to a d3.js script using the package `r2d3`. An extension of the `r2d3` bar chart example to access variables in `data.frame` object would be helpful.

R code:

```
library(r2d3)
data <- data.frame(nums = c(0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.95, 0.40, 0.20))
r2d3(data, script = "test.js")
```

js code:

```
var barHeight = Math.floor(height / data.length);

svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data.nums)
  .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d * width; })
    .attr('height', barHeight)
    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return i * barHeight; })
    .attr('fill', 'steelblue');
```

Error:

```
Error: svg.selectAll(...).data(...).enter is not a function in (test.js#5:4)
TypeError: svg.selectAll(...).data(...).enter is not a function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error occurs because `data.nums` is undefined.

Your `data` variable is not an object containing an array as follows:

```
var data = {
      nums: [0.3,0.6,0.8,0.95,0.40,0.20]
    }
```

But, rather an array containing objects:

```
var data = [
  {nums:0.3},
  {nums:0.6},
  {nums:0.8},
  {nums:0.95},
  {nums:0.40},
  {nums:0.2}
]
```

To keep you `r` side code, we just need to pass the data array itself to `selection.data()` and access the `nums` property of each datum:

```
var barHeight = Math.floor(height / data.length);

svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d.nums * width; })
    .attr('height', barHeight)
    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return i * barHeight; })
    .attr('fill', 'steelblue');
```